# How to include PDF pages without a newpage before the first page?

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I am using pdfpages which works quite well.

But this time, I want to include a 5 page pdf and the first page should be scaled down a bit such that above the first page is enough space for a subsection (in the LaTeX document).

Using just

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
...

\subsection{Interesting Letter}
\includepdf{letter.pdf}
```

does not work, because includepdf inserts a newpage command before the first page.

I looked at the pdfpages manual but could not find options relating to that.

I hacked this command, which kind of works:

```
\newcommand{\insertrep}[1]{%
\hspace*{-2.4cm}
\fbox{\includegraphics[page=1,scale=0.8]{#1}}
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=2-,frame]{#1}
}

\subsection{Interesting Letter}
\insertrep{letter.pdf}
```

The subsection is printed on the same page as the first page of the pdf, but an empty page is inserted before the section ...

The empty page vanishes if I scale the first page to 0.5 - which is too small ...

It seems that \includegraphics inserts an empty page before the graphic, if the inserted graphic violates the margins of the page.

Besides, the hspace value does not always fit.

Thus, my question: How to solve this right?

Comment: Did you try just `\includegraphics`?: PDFs can be used as images by pdfTeX.

Comment: @Joseph Wright, yes, like mentioned in the 2nd part of my post

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the `pagecommand` key:

```
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=1,pagecommand=\subsection{blub}]{testpdf}
```

You get the empty page when you use `\includegraphics` because the graphics are too large for the textbody, so latex tries if it fits on the next page (and then complain). `pdfpages` hides the size of the graphics so it is possible to insert complete pages which overwrites the margins. If you want to insert large graphics with `\includegraphics`: use `eso-pic`.

Comment: Unfortunately, what this actually does is insert a section on its own, and then inserts a pagebreak automatically - which means you cannot have any text between the subsection and the included pdf - even if you scaled it to something like 0.2 of the page... EDIT: actually ok - `\def\excerpt{\section{Blah} .. \\ blah}` and then `pagecommand={\excerpt}` works. Cheers!

Comment: You can also add an introduction to the inserted subsection, e.g., `\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=1,pagecommand={\subsection{blub} This section includes the following attachment.}, offset=0 -1.5cm]{testpdf}`. For better formatting, I've added `offset=0 -1.5cm`.

Comment: You might consider including the `offset` that @Yamaneko mentioned in the answer. At least for me the output showed the pdf overlapping with the subsection-title without it.

Answer (score 59):

For me the following worked just fine:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\section{Section Heading}]{testpdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={}]{testpdf}
```

Comment: Combines well with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62766/8666

Comment: @IoannisFilippidis how do you see `\phantomsection` being used in relation to this answer?

Comment: For example: `\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\phantomsection  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{title} }]{filename}`.

Answer (score 7):

It worked including a minipage.

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \includepdf[scale=0.85,pages=1]{testpdf}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: This worked where none of the other options worked for me (I'm using the book class if it matters).

Answer (score 6):

I tried this but the PDF overwrote the section heading.
Add `[offset=0 -3cm]` and the PDF is dropped 3cm. All OK.

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\section{Section Heading}, offset=0 -3cm]{testpdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={}, offset=0 -3cm]{testpdf}
```

I found an issue associated with the documentation of the section number. I added a label to the statements but this label is not recognized when used as a reference. However the TOC has the correct reference in line with that on the actual text on the PDF page.

Any suggestions as to fix this problem?

I am using this example:

```
\chapter{Technical Information}
\section{List of Technical Information}
 Text paragraph.\\
\textbf{Section Heading}  Refer \ref{newlabel} \\

\include[pages=1,pagecommand=\section{section Heading}, offset=0 -3cm]{testpdf}
\label{newlabel}
\includepdf[pages=2- ,pagecommand={ }, offset=0 -3cm]{testpdf}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you include the label within the options e.g:

```
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1},pagecommand=\section{Datenblätter Sensorik}\label{sec:appendix_db_sens}]{content/99_appendix/db/sensors/ds_kistler_9047C.pdf}
```

Then the label gets created correctly

Comment: Worked for me when using the PDF in a appendix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor issue for labeling in the above code. Try this one

```
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages={1},pagecommand=\section{sec:secname \label{sec:seclabel}}]{figname.pdf}
```

Note that the label is within the {} of section name.