# Getting pax/pdfpages to work with xelatex?

Tags: xetex, pdfpages, pax

Please consider the following MWE, in a form of a batch file, which creates two tex files (one of them gets `\includepdf`d in the other):

```
cat > insert.tex <<'EOF'
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue} %


\begin{document}

A test of url: \href{http://www.example.com}{http://www.example.com}

A test of cite: \cite{mytest}




\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{mytest} Just Testing, \emph{Just Testing}, 2012.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
EOF

pdflatex insert.tex
pdflatex insert.tex

pdfannotextractor insert.pdf


cat > includer.tex <<'EOF'
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red, citecolor=red, filecolor=red, urlcolor=red} %

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pax}


\begin{document}

\def\excerpt{\section{A test of inclusion}

Turns out we cannot just use includepdf in between section and
text, even if it is scaled down - must define the whole section
and use it as a pagecommand, see \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/}.

}

\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.6,frame,pagecommand={\excerpt},link]{insert.pdf}


\end{document}
EOF

# pdflatex includer.tex
# pdflatex includer.tex

xelatex includer.tex
xelatex includer.tex
```

If I compile the second file, `includer.tex`, with `pdflatex` - then all the links work fine in the `includer.pdf`.

However, if I try to compile `includer.tex` with `xelatex` (as in the example), I get:

```
! Package pax Error: Missing pdfTeX in PDF mode.

See the pax package documentation for explanation.
```

... after which, the process can continue - but no links in the included pdf work.

The error message is actually quite clear, in that `pax` doesn't as of yet support `xelatex` - but I was wandering if anyone, maybe, knows a hack/workaround, so the links would work also with `xelatex`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pax` uses the following `pdftex` primitives:

```
\pdfstartlink
\pdfendlink
\pdfescapename
\pdfdest
\pdfstrcmp
```

Only the last one has a counterpart in `xetex`. You may have better luck with `luatex`, but `\pdfstrcmp` and `\pdfescapename` are only available as `\pdf@strcmp` and `\pdf@escapename` by loading `pdftexcmds`, so possibly

```
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\let\pdfescapename=\pdf@escapename
\let\pdfstrcmp=\pdf@strcmp
\makeatother
\usepackage{pax}
```

can work. There's nothing similar with `xetex`, that uses a completely different model for inserting hyperlinks.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @egreg - wasn't even aware that there are different `pdftex` primitives supported between engines (`pdftex`, `xetex`, `luatex`) - and it's great to see there's some hope with `luatex` as it also supports (most) of the `fontspec` stuff... Many thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau Unfortunately, my experiment failed, because my Perl doesn't have a module required by `pdfannotextractor`. I will retry.

Comment: Hi @egreg - strange, because I actually tried your solution (_on my actual work, not on the MWE, though_), and works damn fine with my .pax files and `lualatex` so far!? `:)` Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau I tried on a machine where Perl has no problem, and it seems to work: differently from `xetex`, `luatex` descends from `pdftex` and shares many of the specific primitives introduced by it. Some of them have been removed, because they can be emulated with Lua functions (what `pdftexcmds` does).