# Unknown errors with pax package with lualatex compiling

Tags: errors, luatex, pdfpages, pax

We have some `document.tex`-file with hyperlinks:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{key}
 E = mc^c
\end{equation}

\eqref{key}

\end{document}
```

I created a `document.pax`-file based on above `.tex`-file using `Java x64 (build 1.8.0_201-b09)` based on these answers:

[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78863/how-to-install-pdfbox-on-windows-so-it-works-with-pax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78863/how-to-install-pdfbox-on-windows-so-it-works-with-pax)

http://bryanwweber.com/writing/personal/2014/04/13/use-pax-to-extract-and-include-links-from-external-pdf-files-in-latex-on-windows/

[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60201/getting-pax-pdfpages-to-work-with-xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60201/getting-pax-pdfpages-to-work-with-xelatex)

```
\[{pax}{0.1l}\\
\[{file}{\<653A5C476172626167655C646F63756D656E742E706466\>}{
  Size={23982},
  Date={D:20190404100715+03'00'},
}\\
\[{pagenum}{1}\\
\[{page}{1}{0 0 612 792}{}\\
\[{annot}{1}{Link}{151.59 623.861 158.564 635.816}{GoTo}{
  C={[1 0 0]},
  H={/I},
  DestLabel={1},
  Border={[0 0 1]},
}\\
\[{dest}{1}{1}{XYZ}{
  DestY={657.235},
  DestX={286.459},
}\\
```

Next, I want to insert `document.pdf` from `document.tex` into another `Main.pdf` compiled from  `Main.tex` with `LuaLaTeX`:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = utf8


\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}%{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\let\pdfescapename=\pdf@escapename
\let\pdfstrcmp=\pdf@strcmp
\makeatother
\usepackage{pax}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{document.pdf}

\end{document}
```

But I get an error `Undefined control sequence` and `Main.pdf` appears with a strange string `namePAX@document.pax@1xyz`
[image]

`.log`-file

```
File: document.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use document.pdf, page 1>
Package luatex.def Info: document.pdf , page1 used on input line 23.
(luatex.def)             Requested size: 614.58406pt x 795.3441pt.
 (./document.pax
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...X@raise \hb@xt@ \z@ {\kern \PAX@right \pdfdest 
                                                  \PAX@name \PAX@type \relax...
l.17 }
    \\
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

)
```

Previously, this code worked fine, but after some updates these errors appeared.
I use TexLive 2018.

Comment: which control sequence is undefined?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer My TXS shows only last line of the .pax-file `}\\ `  as wrong and Main.pdf output has the strange string `namePAX@document.pax@1xyz`

Comment: Don't look only at the editor output, check the log-file. That's what it is for.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Related files here https://www.upload.ee/download/9785694/e9376a04c016152c4e12/Main.zip

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Error arise after second compilation

Comment: I will not download a zip to debug your problem. Find the log and the error message and copy it in your question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I  think that it is ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...X@raise \hb@xt@ \z@ {\kern \PAX@right \pdfdest 
                                                  \PAX@name \PAX@type \relax...
l.17 }
    \\

Comment: And one warning `warning  (pdf backend): unreferenced destination with name 'PAX@document.pax@1'`

Comment: grr. I wrote "copy it in your question" (and with the correct line breaking and indentation). Comments are not a useful place for this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer done

Comment: \pdfdest is not defined in luatex anymore. Try `\usepackage{luatex85}` (no garanty that it works, pax was not written for luatex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanx, your solution with `\usepackage{luatex85}` work.