# Using pax with lualatex

Tags: pdftex, luatex, pdfpages, pax

I'm publishing a magazine about chameleons (http://www.agchamaeleons.de/downloads/), individual articles are built with pdflatex / biber / pax, and finally are all assembled together using pax to keep the links intact. There are only links whithin each article (ie. mostly clickable references to the bibliography, rarely links to other pages within that article.)

The wrapping LaTeX document then includes all the articles and generates a new TOC linking the individual articles:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{One article title}
\includepdf[pages=-]{articles/Jan-Benedict-Glaw--Angelesen-2/article.pdf}
\clearpage
\phantomsection
```

This works quite well using pdflatex, but I'm considering to move to lualatex. However, with lualatex, even compiling the individual articles fails:

```
jbglaw@charon:~/Dropbox/AG Chamäleons/Chamaeleo-LaTeX/articles/Jan-Benedict-Glaw--Angelesen-2 [master] $ lualatex -recorder --shell-escape article.tex 
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) 
 system commands enabled.
[...]
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pax/pax.sty

! Package pax Error: pdfTeX is too old.

See the pax package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.36   }
      %
```

Am I riding a dead horse trying to get pax running with lualatex? I'd certainly try to build a minimum (non-)working example, but maybe there's a completely different way to include PDFs with lualatex and keep internal links intact?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am afraid `pax` has been written for `pdftex`. [This question about `pax` and `xetex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60211/82917) contains an answer by egreg which might work for `luatex`. Caveat: the answer is 8 years old, so I have no idea if it still applies.

Comment: I have an reimplemention for luatex, it is currently internal but if you are interested to test you can contact me.

Comment: It looks like it has been [released](https://ctan.org/pkg/newpax) and it works pretty well with LuaTeX.