# Removing blank page before chapter

Tags: chapters

When I start my chapter by including a figure, the preceeding page automatically becomes blank. I'm using the report document class. I have a main .tex file from which I include  other .tex files containing the chapters.

For example when I use

```
\chapter{Chapter 5}

\fbox{ \includegraphics[page=1,scale=1]{mypdf.pdf}}
```

It will automatically generate a blank page before chapter 5. 
However if I use

```
\chapter{Chapter 5}

Just some text ...
```

It does not include a blank page.

How can I remove the blank page in the first case?

Comment: You are trying to insert one full page in the same page where `Chapter 1. Something` is printed. There is no enough space there. Hence latex moves it to the next page. Try scaling the picture down: `\fbox{ \includegraphics[page=1,scale=.7]{mypdf.pdf}}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @HarishKumar The page of the pdf is printed on the same page as Chapter 1. Something. So inserting the full page on the same page as the chapter title is not a problem. 
However your solution does work: if I scale it enough the blank page will go away. But I would like to include it full scale though.. rescaling isn't really an option.

Comment: You shouldn't include pictures like this but put them into a `figure` environment, which is invented _exactly_ to avoid problems like yours. You use the environment as follows:  `\begin{figure}\includegraphics{...}\end{figure}`. That way LaTeX will find a nice position for your figure and won't leave white space at the start of your chapter.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen If I use \begin{figure} ..\end{figure} the blank page indeed goes away. However now I'm unable to fit the image on the same page as the chapter title. Now I have "Chapter 5. Something" - blank page - page with figure. The figure needs to be on the same page as the chapter title.
Even rescaling it (which is not an option) doesn't move the image to the Chapter page.

Comment: Ok I solved it using the following:
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\section{Section Heading}]{testpdf} which I have found here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/how-to-include-pdf-pages-without-a-newpage-before-the-first-page

Comment: What about trimming the picture `\includegraphics[trim=...]{...}` (assuming you've loaded the `graphicx` package)?

Comment: Such problem occurs, since when you type `\chapter{TEST}`, Latex inserts some vertical space below TEST and then, the first line of your text; So, the text fills approximately half of a chapter page. For this reason, you could not insert your figure in a full scale, in a chapter page.