# Included PDF as first page creates empty page before it

Tags: pdf, page-breaking, pdfpages

For my thesis I have to use a specific first page, which is only available as Word.

I filled it and saved it as PDF and included it with my thesis with

```
\includepdf[pages=-,templatesize={145mm}{210mm},noautoscale=true,offset=-20 -190]{Frontpage.pdf}
```

The problem which occurs is that I have an empty first page befor the wanted first page.

On Google I found solutions like [How to include PDF pages without a newpage before the first page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/how-to-include-pdf-pages-without-a-newpage-before-the-first-page)

But even with something like "pagecommand={\section{Frontpage}\thispagestyle{empty}}" the only result is, that I have another entry in my table of contents.

How can I make this thing work?

Antoher solution which would work for me would be a Word to LaTeX converter which converts the Word Document as it is.
Everthing I found in this direction had problems with positions and graphics of the Word Document.

**Edit**: I found out, that the problem is because of my used documentclass. For my thesis I use this one:

- Thesis.xls http://pastebin.com/yavTC0mu
- Example: http://pastebin.com/fyRKADmf
- Result: http://files.liebich.co/test_Thesis.pdf

The Result with this looks like this: 
With documentclass book it is working correct:

- Example: http://pastebin.com/VC9TCFve
- Result: http://files.liebich.co/test_Book.pdf

Greetings
Sören

Comment: I cannot adequately reproduce the problem. If need be one could discard the first page using [`atbegshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi)'s `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard`.

Comment: @Werner I added the example to make my problem more clear :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The abstract seems to be programmed wrongly:

```
\newcommand\abstract[1]{
  \btypeout{Zusammenfassung}
  \addtotoc{Zusammenfassung}
  \thispagestyle{plain}
  \begin{center}{\huge{\textit{Zusammenfassung}} \par}\end{center}
  {\normalsize #1}
  \vfil\vfil\null

}
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
```

note that the first line says `\newcommand` not `\newenvironment`. Thus the

```
{
  \vfil\vfil\vfil\null
  \cleardoublepage
}
```

is never picked up, lives on and leaves that stupid blank line.

You will have to change the code in `Thesis.cls` in order to get rid of this.