# Inserting a pdf file after a title causes the tile to be on one page and the pdf to start on the next

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I have a new page, with title. I want my pdf file to show up under the title. However, the pdf shows up on the following page. I want the pdf to be under the title page. Is the issue the size of the pdf? Here's my code:

```
\newpage
\section{Requirements Document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{requirements_xlsx.pdf}
```

Comment: `\includepdf` is meant exactly for including full pages; what you are looking for can be accomplished with `\begin{center}\includegraphics[...]{...}\end{center}`, or something similar.  I think you should clarify your question, though.

Comment: How many pages are in `requirements_xlsx.pdf`?

Comment: @Werner Two pages are in it

Comment: @Gustavo Mezzetti What is unclear?

Comment: It simply stands for the arguments of the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I don't understand what you are saying? You said to clarify my question, so I asked what is unclear?

Comment: As @Mezetti was saying, use `\includegraphics` instead.

Comment: Sorry for answering only this evening, I haven’t logged in again since this morning.  It wasn’t clear to me exactly what output you were looking for.  But now that you have posted the solution you have found by yourself, it has become clear.  And, my previous comment was in reply to another comment, now removed, that was asking about the meaning of `[...]{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer through the following link:

[How to include PDF pages without a newpage before the first page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/how-to-include-pdf-pages-without-a-newpage-before-the-first-page)

I changed my code to be as follows and it works as I wish:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand=\section{Requirements Document}]{requirements_xlsx.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-,pagecommand={}]{requirements_xlsx.pdf}
```