# To insert by pdfpages pdf files closely one after the other without new page

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

I have a few articles as pdf files to be merged in one book.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
Conference proceedings
\includepdf[pages=-]{article01}
\includepdf[pages=-]{article02}
\includepdf[pages=-]{article03}
\end{document}
```

But every articles begins from new page. I need them to follow closely one after another but not from new page each. 
How to do this?

Comment: Do you want to insert small versions of the pdfs? (and not full size?), then perhaps use `\includegraphics` instead.

Comment: Thank you Grimmer. Not small but real size - just the beginning of the next article will follow the previous immediatly not from new page.

Comment: So you want half of the included page to appear? I'm having trouble grasping what it is that you want. Could you edit your post and include a screenshot showing how you want the pages to appear?

Comment: You see, the sections in text do not begin from the new page. I need the same with texts including with \pdfinclude from different pdf files.

Comment: Does [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/how-to-include-pdf-pages-without-a-newpage-before-the-first-page) help?

Comment: I think the command \includepdf сontaines within "new page", how to undo it, I do not know

Comment: The question I linked to contains some discussion about the page breaks. Try using `pagecommand={}` as they recommend in that question

Comment: I tried the same that you did and did not get a new page between the included pdf files.

Comment: Jpi, thank you. Can you send me your real latex text and pdf files you used or upload them somewhere. I don't know how to send files just here from http://tex.stackexchange.com/. If this is impossible please send here defaultxxx@yandex.ru

Comment: Are there any news here?