# \includepdf jumps to new page - can I avoid that?

Tags: pdfpages

For my thesis I shall include some pdf-files in the appendix (i.e. appendix a, b, c etc.). I would like the section title (Appendix of Introduction) and the subsection title (Appendix a: Initial presentation of the project) to be at the top of the page on which the first page of the multi-paged pdf-file start.

First I was doing:

```
\pagebreak

\section*{Appendix of Introduction}

\subsection*{Appendix a: Initial presentation of the project}

\includepdf[pages={ - },scale=0.8,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}] {appendix/Initial-presentation-of-the-project.pdf}
```

That gave me one page with the two titles at the top and the included pdf-file starts on the following page.

After being directed to this thread: [How to include PDF pages without a newpage before the first page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/how-to-include-pdf-pages-without-a-newpage-before-the-first-page)
I figured out how to get the title of the *subsection* on the same page as the included pdf-file, but now the subsection title is on *all* the pages of the included multi-page pdf-file:

```
\pagebreak

\section*{Appendix of Introduction}

\includepdf[pages={ - },scale=0.8,pagecommand=\subsection{Appendix a: Initial presentation of the project}] {appendix/Initial-presentation-of-the-project.pdf}
```

I need to figure out how to have the title of the subsection only on the first page of the appendix (a).

Furthermore, the problem of how to get the title of the *section* on that same page remains as well.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the scale to be lower (like 0.7 or 0.6) for the first page?

Comment: `Have you tried adjusting the scale to be lower (like 0.7 or 0.6) for the first page?`  I have now, but it made no difference. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look at that other thread.

Comment: @flex013: that other thread was a good one. I now have the title of the subsection on the first  page of the included multi-page pdf-file. As I have a number of appendices, next step is to figure out how to have the title of the section on the first page of the first included pdf-file...

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF is only one page, you can treat it like a figure or image file:

```
\pagebreak

\section*{Appendix of Introduction}

\subsection*{Appendix a: Initial presentation of the project}

\newline
\begin{center} %centre on page
\resizebox{0.8 \textwidth}{!}{ %resize inserted page
\includegraphics{{"appendix/Initial-presentation-of-the-project.pdf"}}
} %close resizebox    
\end{center}
```

You can also use options to resize graphics (`\includegraphics[width=16cm]{{"appendix/Initial-presentation-of-the-project.pdf"}}`) but `resizebox` will scale to the size of your page. This also works to include vector images in documents or beamer presentations.

Remember to include `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your document header.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but I should have explained that it is a multi-page pdf-file.

Comment: In that case, this command will include the first page with section headings. `\includepdf[pages=2-last, scale=0.8]` should fill in the rest.

Comment: I tried your fix and it almost works. It does pose some new problems though. I created a new thread: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440046/title-of-subsection-on-included-multi-page-pdf

Comment: Btw, \includegraphics did not accept `pages=2-last` but did accept `pages={2- }`.

Comment: Sorry, I suspected that issue may arise but didn’t have a reproducible MWE to test the code. `\includepdf[pages = 2-, width = 0.8 \textwidth]` ought to do it then.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry about the MWE, but it is too complex for me to create. Please the the new thread to see another issue, your solution provides.

Comment: Normally I’d edit the solution here but I’ve given an updated example of code with the new question to avoid confusion. I understand than an MWE is not always easy to provide but you will get more (and better) answers if you provide one in the future since it’s easier to help you. I’ve encountered similar issues before so I’d expect this to work but it’s harder to test without an example, it’s just a caveat to answers without a working MWE that’s all.