# title of (sub)section on included multi-page pdf

Tags: pdfpages, includegraphics

This is a follow-up on another thread in which I got advise on how to \includepdf with section and subsection titles on the included pdf: [\includepdf jumps to new page - can I avoid that?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440005/includepdf-jumps-to-new-page-can-i-avoid-that/440006?noredirect=1#comment1105008_440006)

The proposed \resizebox + \includegraphics solution does seem to solve the with single-page pdfs. However, with the solution in the above thread, my multi-page pdf is treated as a single-paged, i.e. only the first page is included. As is also suggested, the rest of the pages in the multi-page def-file can afterwards be included by \includepdf[pages={2- }.

Combining these two commands are not very convenient but could be feasible, except the first page is scaled and positioned different from the rest of the pages.

For me, it is quite complex to make a MWE in this case and hence I will (at least for now) just present the code and a snapshot of the output file.

```
\begin{center} %centre on page
    \resizebox{1.0 \textwidth}{!}{ %resize inserted page
        \includegraphics{appendix/Initial-presentation-of-the-project.pdf}
    } %close resizebox    
\end{center}

\includepdf[pages={2- }, scale=0.755,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}] {appendix/Initial-presentation-of-the-project.pdf}
```

Please note the different scale values in the code snippet and the different positionss of the boarders on page 35 and 36 in the left side of the output file. The following pages are similar to page 36.

[image: The boarders of pages 35 and 36]

After using the latest suggestion by @Tom Kelly, the size issue is solved. The issue with position is not used but has minimised:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the included page at the same position on each page? i.e., so there is a gap at the top of each page large enough for a heading, even if the heading only appears on the first page of each appendix?

Comment: I actually didn't think of hat, but I think would be neat.

Comment: I have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\includepdf` has a `width` argument. Use this instead of `scale` to give the exact width:

```
\pagebreak

\section*{Appendix of Introduction}

\subsection*{Appendix a: Initial presentation of the project}

\newline
\begin{center} %centre on page
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ %resize inserted page
\includegraphics[page = 1]{{"appendix/Initial-presentation-of-the-project.pdf"}}
} %close resizebox    
\end{center}

\includepdf[pages = {2- }, width = \textwidth, pagecommand = {\thispagestyle{plain}}] {appendix/Initial-presentation-of-the-project.pdf}
```

Comment: Thanks for the persistence, @Tom Kelly. This is much better, but actually there is still a little difference between the position of the first (p. 35) and the latter pages. Since I cannot add ta snapshot here, I will edit the OP to add one there.

Comment: Do you think we can solve that?

Comment: I suspect one of two issues: 1) the remaining pages must scaled to allow space of the section headers (if you want the width to match). Perhaps scaling by height rather than width would address this. 2) the first page is centred and the remainder of the PDF is aligned to the left. I’d suggest to centre align the PDF pages: you may need to do this as demonstrated for includegraphics since I don’t see an option for alignment in the includepdf documentation: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf#page2

Comment: There is no doubt, that the first page is the problem. The following are right in the middle of the page, while the first page is slightly off the center line.

Comment: I just tried to omit the \begin{center} and \end{center}. Apparently it makes no difference.

Comment: Perhaps it is aligned to the text margins rather than centre of the page. This may be intentional for a thesis, depending on your document style (to leave space for comments or binding). The `\includepdf` does have an `offset` option to allow you to move remaining pages accordingly. I try to use relative solutions rather than hardcoding but it’ll move it over.

Comment: When printing my thesis, the text is right in the middle of the page. Hence, I still think the issue is with the \includegraphics

Comment: I have almost solved it now. Still I wonder why `\textwidth` differ between `\includegraphics` and `\includepdf`. Anyway, by adding  `\hspace*{-5mm}` in front `\includegraphics` I have been able to align the left sides of the border. There is still a slight displacement between the right boarder of the first and the following pages. It might not get any  batter than this, so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package called `pdfoverlay` which allows you to overlay text on to an existing PDF. With slight modification to the macro that positions the PDF on to the page, you could make it place each PDF at the bottom of the page text and scaled to `\textwidth`.

You could use the `adjustbox` to frame each page easily.

It's possible to put each PDF page anywhere at any size on the page.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% use adjustbox to frame each page
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdfoverlay}
% Options for include graphics to scale to text width and frame each page
\pdfoverlaySetGraphicsOptions{keepaspectratio, width=\textwidth, frame}
% slightly redefine \__pdfoverlay_format_pdf_page: so that pdf page is placed
% at the bottom of the page text, rather than at the centre of the page
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \__pdfoverlay_format_pdf_page:
  {
    \AtTextUpperLeft
      {
        \put(0,\LenToUnit{-\textheight})
          {
            \use:x
              {
                \exp_not:N \includegraphics
                  [ \clist_use:Nn \g__pdfoverlay_graphics_options_clist { , } ]
                  { \g__pdfoverlay_pdf_file_name_str }
              }
          }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\section*{Appendixes}
\subsection*{Appendix A}
\pdfoverlaySetPDF{first.pdf}
\pdfoverlayIncludeToLastPage
\null\clearpage
\subsection*{Appendix B}
\pdfoverlaySetPDF{second.pdf}
\pdfoverlayIncludeToLastPage
\null\clearpage
\subsection*{Appendix C}
\pdfoverlaySetPDF{third.pdf}
\pdfoverlayIncludeToLastPage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. Just to be sure: Are you aware that the my pdfs have multiple pages? Should it still work?

Comment: Yes, the `\pdfoverlayIncludeToLastPage` macro includes all pages in a multi page pdf

Comment: I am getting a `File 'pdfoverlay.sty' not found. \pdfoverlaySetGraphicsOptions` error

Comment: It's only been in texlive and miktex for a couple of months, so you might need to upgrade packages or grab it off ctan

Comment: I actually have some other packages that need upgrading, but I don't knoe how to do it. Is there an easy way?

Comment: I have chosen to use a modified version of Tom Kelly's suggestion above. Thanks so much for taking time to try to help me out. Once your package is included I will look into it. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

IMO  the `\resizebox`+ `\includegraphics` combination is a heavy hack that doesn't take advantage of the `pdfpages` package which was considered as an option. The cropping and size control of this package can be used for a simpler  code, if one use  the powerfull `pagecommand` option.

Here is a MWE which produces a regular appendix, and the a second one the content of which is a portion of the [pdf doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) of the `pdfpackage` itself. I assume that the first page you want to include gas a usefull height significantly smaller that the regular page, as the chapter header takes some place

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\chapter{My first appendix}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\includepdf[width=\paperwidth,pages={1},trim={0in 1.5in 0in 5in},clip,
pagecommand={\chapter{My second appendix}},offset={0mm -2in}]{pdfpages.pdf}

\includepdf[width=\paperwidth,pages={2-4},trim={0in 0in 0in 0in},clip,
pagecommand={},offset={0mm -0.5in}]{pdfpages.pdf}

\end{document}
```

In this code, one include a selected part of the first page (defined by the two non vanishing `trim` parameters. The offset is used to vertically position the portion to iake in two account the headein height and the footer height in the master document (rule of thumb : bottom trim value minus height of the bottom margin).

For the other pages, page command must be kept empty to ensute taht the running headers will be typeset, and the offset is still used to acomodate the different layout of the two documents. Result looks like (width the frame option added in `\includepdf` to visualize the offsets) :

[image]

With this strategy, there is no need to do anything to keep the initial text fully unscaled. Obviously, your would have to adjust the trim and offset paramters if you want to cut out the page numbers of the source PDF.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use chapter, and all my pdf pages a originally A4 and have to stay that way, though scaling is ok. Would it work with sections and full pages?

Comment: The short answer i YES.

Hoever I'm not sure to understand. I'mmore  used ith ``book`` where appendices are ``\chapter`` but actually  in ``article `` they are ``\section``.  The described solution works exactly the same way if you replace ``\chapter`` by ``\section``. But the IMO the ``fullpage`` doesn't make sense, because the section header takes  some space. If the top of the first included page is sufficiently empty, it will nevertheless work without trim nor offset. But in the opposite (more general) ill need some cropping or some scaling.

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me keep the section and the subsection title at the same page (I am using the report document class).

Comment: Of course ! As i said, witt neither crop nor scaling you can't,  as i tried to say in my previous comment.. If yiu dont want tu uses this aporach, you will  need  resort to an overlay lechanisl, as suggested in another answer, or maybe more simply using the eso-pic package

Comment: In the end I have chosen to use Tom Kelly's suggestion above with a slight modification. But thanks a lot for trying to help me out.