# Appendix Title no forced page break

Tags: appendix

I would like to have the title (or rather "section") "Appendix" (German: Anhang) right at the top of the page as it is, but with the pdf, I tried to include as an appendix, following right away without having a forced pagebreak.

Is this possible?
Currently it looks like this: [image: Output]

Thank you very much in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=standardclasses,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{\mbox{\thesection.\enskip$|$\enskip}}% <- changed
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,% changed to a positive value, if afterindent=false is set (needs version 3.26b)
  afterindent=false,% < - added, needs version 3.26b
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{.} % replace \autodot by a fixed dot for section entries
   ]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{paragraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subparagraph}
  \usepackage{authblk}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*\appendixmore{% see the KOMA-Script documentation
  \clearpage
  \addsec{\appendixname}%
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIGURES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
\counterwithout{table}{section}
\begin{document}
\appendix
%\input{figures}
%\pagebreak
%\input{tables}
%\pagebreak
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.75,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}\subsection{Auszug aus dem Tosa Nikki} \footnotesize{\textsc{Ki} (1957): \textit{Tosa Nikki} [Das Tagebuch von Tosa].}]{Iwanami1957TosaNikki.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2,scale=0.75,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Iwanami1957TosaNikki.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [How to include PDF pages without a newpage before the first page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5911/134144) could be interesting.

Comment: I checked that too, but to me it looks like what I just tried, doesn't it? @leandriis

You can use the pagecommand key:

\includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=1,pagecommand=\subsection{blub}]{testpdf}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `\addsec{\appendixname}` from the definition of `\appendixmore`.

```latex
\newcommand*\appendixmore{%
  \clearpage
  %\addsec{\appendixname}% <- remove this
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%
}
```

Then you can add this command to option `pagecommand` of the first included page.

```latex
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.75,
  pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}%
    \addsec{\appendixname}% <- add this
    \subsection{Auszug aus dem Tosa Nikki}
    {\footnotesize\textsc{Ki} (1957): \textit{Tosa Nikki} [Das Tagebuch von Tosa].\endgraf}% \footnotesize is a switch
  ]{example-image-a4.pdf}
```

Note that `\footnotesize` is a switch and does not take an argument.

Example using `example-image-a4.pdf` provided by package `mwe.sty`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headings=standardclasses,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\renewcommand\sectionformat{\mbox{\thesection.\enskip$|$\enskip}}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=2\baselineskip,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip,
  tocentrynumberformat=\def\autodot{.}
   ]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{paragraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1\baselineskip,
  afterskip=.5\baselineskip]{subparagraph}
  \usepackage{authblk}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*\appendixmore{%
  \clearpage
  %\addsec{\appendixname}% <- remove this
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}%
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIGURES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}% loads also graphicx
%\usepackage{graphicx}%loaded by pdfpages
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{pdflscape}% maybe better than lscape
%\usepackage{booktabs}

%\usepackage{chngcntr}% only needed with older TeX Distributions
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\figurename}{Abb.}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\listtablename}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\tablename}{Tab.}
\counterwithout{table}{section}

\begin{document}
\appendix
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.75,
  pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}%
    \addsec{\appendixname}% <- add this
    \subsection{Auszug aus dem Tosa Nikki}
    {\footnotesize\textsc{Ki} (1957): \textit{Tosa Nikki} [Das Tagebuch von Tosa].\endgraf}% \footnotesize is a switch
  ]{example-image-a4.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.75,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{example-image-a4.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remarks:

1. If you want to change `\listfigurename` etc. use `\providecaptionname` as in the example above.
2. Package `chngcntr` is not needed, if you do not use an older TeX Distribution.
3. `pdfpages` loads `graphicx`.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) It worked!