# Appendix, landscape mode, unwanted blank page

Tags: pdfpages, landscape, blank-page, appendix

I have a PDF in landscape mode created from excel. I want to include this in an Appendix with heading, followed by each appendix as a section. My attempt is shown below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
...
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\section*{Appendices}
\section{First appendix}
\includepdf[scale= 0.8,pages={1}]{example.pdf}
\section{Second appendix}
```

I face two problems:

1. "Appendices" and "First Appendix" is left alone and the pdf is put on the next page. I tried to fix it using scale, without success.
2. The PDF is no longer in landscape mode even though the original PDF is. I expected the PDF to get imported directly in with a 90° angle. As a result, the PDF is too small to be be read.

Attempts with `\begin{landscape}` in Latex has left the problem unsolved.

Answers are appreciated!

Comment: As always on this site, if you want help, then please post a full minimal example. Don;t post unfinished sniplets like this and expect others to fill in the details. Make something we can copy and test as is. For image replacements you can use say `\rule{4cm}{4cm}` or one of the images provided by the mwe package (see the available images names on https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe)

Comment: By default it is assumed that pages included by `\includepdf` are in portrait mode. Adding `landscape=true` to the list of optional parameters of `\includepdf` should do the trick for the landscape version. For avoiding the enforced pagebreak being inserted by default see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/ for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, epR8GaYuh! :)