# Includepdf jumps a page down

Tags: pdfpages

I have tried to use includepdf of a PowerPoint in Appendix.
It imports the pdf but it jumps a page down from my title on a newpage.
I then tried naming the section inside includepdf but then the title is repeated each time a new slide is added with a number in front.
I just want the first title and the first slide to show after then no titles.

Code of Appendix:

```
 \section*{Appendix}
\appendix
\section{PowerPoint for the first learning course}
%\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
 % \includepdf[pages=1]{pictures/Dag 1 intro.pdf}
%\end{minipage}
\includepdf[pages=-]{pictures/Dag 1 intro.pdf}
```

Tried looking over here:
[How to include PDF pages without a newpage before the first page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/how-to-include-pdf-pages-without-a-newpage-before-the-first-page) which had the same problem but it could not resolve it for me for some reason

Regards

Comment: Includepdf always inserts a full page, you cannot have section and Includepdf on the same page

Comment: Therefore you may want to include the first page of the PDF as a normal "image" to avoid the page break, and then include the rest of the pages with \includepdf. `\includegraphics[page=1]{pictures/Dag 1 intro.pdf} \includepdf[pages={2-}]{picttures/Dag 1 Intro.pdf}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `picturecommand*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages,showframe}

\newsavebox{\includematerial}

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

Some text

\clearpage

\appendix
\sbox\includematerial{%
  \parbox[b][\paperheight][t]{\paperwidth}{%
    \vspace*{\dimeval{1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip-2\baselineskip}}
    \hspace*{\dimeval{1in+\oddsidemargin}}%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
      \section*{Appendix}
      \section{Slides for the first learning course}
    }%
  }%
}
\includepdf[
  pages=1-3,
  scale=0.5,
  picturecommand*={\usebox{\includematerial}}
]{some.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Correctly positioning the material is a bit of a black art… The material is placed at the bottom left of the page, so we need to move it at the appropriate spot by using the standard lengths.

Note that `showframe` is only added for debugging.

[image]