# Which should be the workflow of creating figures with AutoCad to insert them into LaTex?

Tags: graphics, floats

I was wondering if someone that uses AutoCad to create figures that will later on get imported into LaTex could share with me his/her workflow.

I used to export an AutoCad figure as a pdf document to then make a screenshot of it so to insert it into LaTex. But I found this method a little crappy, since line widths don't get conserved, textsize gets messed up and it is a pretty slow process.

Is there any way to smoothly work together with AutoCad and LaTex?

Comment: Include the exported pdf directly (graphicx package, `\includegraphics{figure}`)? Or do I miss something?

Comment: IIRC, AutoCAD drawings are usually complete letter/A4 pages? In this case, I would think [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package is what you want. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5911/) is another question with a simple example. Edit: (after exporting PDF from AutoCAD)