# Include PDF with section title only on first page

Tags: macros, pdf, pdfpages

As suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85613), I'm using `\includepdf` to insert several multi-page PDF files of musical scores into a LaTeX document:

```
\newcommand{\insertScore}[3] {
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
  \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=1,pagecommand=\section*{#2}]{#1/score.pdf}
  \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=2-,pagecommand={}]{#1/score.pdf}

  … more stuff following
}
```

However, while most of these PDFs consist of two or more pages, some have only one single page, which makes the second `\includepdf` fail. Is there any way to work around this issue without knowing in advance, how many pages the included PDF will consist of? The LaTeX file is generated automatically in this project, therefore using different commands for different PDFs isn't really an option ...

Comment: I posted an answer, but generally it is much better to provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/48973) (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) than code fragments like this. This allows people to reproduce your problem and test their solutions. It also often helps you in understanding your own problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test the number of pages in the PDF first (cf. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198091/48973)).

```latex
\newcommand{\insertScore}[3] {%
  \pdfximage{#1/score.pdf}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=1,pagecommand=\section*{#2}]{#1/score.pdf}%
  \ifnum\pdflastximagepages>1\relax
    \includepdf[scale=0.8,pages=2-,pagecommand={}]{#1/score.pdf}%
  \fi
  %
  % … more stuff following
}
```